# How do I send form input into a PHP array that I can continue to add input to?

Tags: php

I have developed a site that allows a user to enter their name, email, and a comment.  I am using the POST function to send the input to another PHP page (comment.php) where it will display the name and comment, detect any duplicate emails, and let the user know whether or not the comment was added or if it was a duplicate.  On comment.php, the array is also written to a text file (file.txt).  From there, another user can go back to the main page to add another comment.

At the moment, the user input is sent to comment.php where it is added to an array and written to the text file but every time I try to add another user input to add to the array, the previous entry is overwritten.

main.php:

```
<form method="post" action="comment.php">
      <label for="fname">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required autocomplete="off"> <br>
      <label for="fname">E-mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" required autocomplete="off"> <br>
      <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
      <textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form">
    </form>
```

sends to comment.php:

```
<?php
    $commentArray = array();
    array_push($commentArray,$_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['comments']);
    $file=fopen("file.txt", "a");
    file_put_contents("file.txt", print_r($commentArray, true));
    fclose($file);
    if($file == true){
        echo ("<h1>Comments Added</h1><hr>");
        echo ("<br>Name: ").$commentArray[0];
        echo ("<br>Comments: ").$commentArray[2];
    }else{
        echo ("<h1>Comments Not Added</h1><hr>");
        echo ("One per person!  You have already left comments for this posting.");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You're appending to the file, so it shouldn't be overwritten in there. Have you checked? The array itself isn't overwritten as such, because each time you submit the form, a new request is made to the server, 
and  the php script runs again from scratch, values from previous executions are not saved - that's why we use files etc to store things more permanently

Comment: So if you want to see all the saved items, you need to add some code which reads data back from the file and echoes it

Comment: You should consider using a database. Files are not well suited for concurrent access (race condition incoming!)

Comment: If you do use text files, consider e.g. `json_encode` instead of `print_r` for serializing your data, assuming you want to do more than view dumps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. **(1)** file_put_contents() acts as both fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() combined, so using fopen() and fclose() is superfluous. Also **(2)** when you call fopen(), you correctly set the mode to "a" so that contents will be appended, but since you also call file_put_contents() without using the FILE_APPEND flag, it still overwrites the contents.

Your options are thus either **(a)** to only use file_put_contents() with the FILE_APPEND flag as the third argument, or instead **(b)** use fwrite() and thus your "a" mode on the fopen() call will be allowed to work correctly.